Prove $5 \mid a^2+b^2+c^2$
Given that $a, b, c$ are integers, $a, b, c > 0$ and $5 \mid a+b+c$, $5 \mid 2ab+3bc+4ca$, prove that: $$5 \mid a^2+b^2+c^2$$
What I tried:
$5 \mid (a+b+c)^2=2ab+2bc+2ca+a^2+b^2+c^2 = a^2+b^2+c^2+2ab+3bc+4ca - bc - 2 ca$
so we need to prove $5 \mid bc +2ca$, that's true if $5 \mid a$ or $5 \mid b$ or $5 \mid c$, then i couldn't process much. Any hints?

You can run through the $5^3$ possible values of $a, b, c \pmod{5}$ and check if/that the only solution is $ a = b=c = 0 \pmod{5}$.

Hints towards a solution. If you're stuck, show what you've tried.
Show the following:

$ a \equiv - (b+c) \pmod {5}$, and similar.
$ ab+ac \equiv - a^2 \pmod{5}$, and similar.
Find integers such that $$ 2ab+3bc+4ca \equiv P (ab+bc) + Q(bc+ca) + R (ca+ab) \pmod{5}.$$
$ 4a^2 \equiv 2b^2 \pmod{5}$.

The goal is to get an equation relating the squares $a^2, b^2, c^2$. Depending on your integers above, you might get a different equation. If so, that's fine as long as you can prove the next step.


Hence $ a \equiv b \equiv 0 \pmod{5}$ and thus $ c \equiv 0 \pmod{5}$.

Per my comment, this is the only solution. We could have tested all 125 cases, or worked though the above logic.


Hence $25 \mid a^2 + b^2 + c^2$.

This would have been a stronger and hence more interesting statement to prove. It would not have given away that $ a\equiv b\equiv c \equiv 0 \pmod{5}$ is the only solution set.




$\!\!\bmod 5\!:\,\ \overbrace{ 0\equiv 2ab\!+\!\color{#c00}c\:\!(3b\!+\!4a)}^{\textstyle\!\!\! {\ \ \rm subst}\ \ \color{#c00}c\:\!\equiv -a\!-\!b_{\phantom{|}}}\equiv \underbrace{a^2+\color{#0a0}2\:\!b^2\Rightarrow b\equiv 0}_{\textstyle\!\!\!\! \color{#0a0}{-2}\not\equiv n^2}\,$ $\Rightarrow a\equiv 0\Rightarrow c\equiv 0.$ $\ \ \bf\small QED$

Same proof works for  $,5\mid iab+jbc+kca,$ when $,i\equiv j+k,$ and $,\color{#0a0}{-jk}\not\equiv n^2\pmod{!5}\ \ $
